# How to use the coordinate name in round around in tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I'm a student majoring in mechanical engineering and I'm working with plotting the deformation of two links connected at an certain angle. The schematic diagram of the two links is shown below

[image]

I want to use the package `pgfplots` to plot the deformation of the links. Now I have calculated the deformation of the two links at some nodes. Suppose the deformations of the two links both are

```
\begin{filecontents*}{data1.tex}
0.  0.
0.1 0.00944826
0.2 0.0308185
0.3 0.0541806
0.4 0.0711639
0.5 0.0760562
0.6 0.0666065
0.7 0.0442508
0.8 0.0136516
0.9 -0.0183828
1.  -0.0443726
\end{filecontents*}
```

Where the first column is the distance along the axial direction of the link and the second column is the transverse deformation. To intuitively show the deformations, I want to use the `mesh` option of the `\addplot` command to color the line according to the deformation by setting `point meta=y`. In addition, I want to make the deformation plotted with respect to the undeformed configuration, as shown below.

[image]

The code I write is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{data.dat}
        0.  0.
        0.1 0.00944826
        0.2 0.0308185
        0.3 0.0541806
        0.4 0.0711639
        0.5 0.0760562
        0.6 0.0666065
        0.7 0.0442508
        0.8 0.0136516
        0.9 -0.0183828
        1.  -0.0443726
    \end{filecontents*}
\pagestyle{empty}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableread{data.dat}\data
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            % hide axis,
            colormap/jet,
            point meta rel=per plot,
            ymax=10
        ]
            \addplot[
                mesh,
                point meta=abs(y),
            ] table {\data} coordinate (endpoint);
            % the above command plots the deformation of the first link
            \addplot[
                mesh,
                x filter/.code={\pgfmathparse{#1+1}\pgfmathresult},
                y filter/.code={\pgfmathparse{#1+-0.0443726}\pgfmathresult},
                rotate around={45:(1.,-0.0443726)},% works
                %rotate around={45:(endpoint)},% not works
                ] table {\data};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

In the above code, I use `x filter` and `rotate around` to achieve the rotation and shift of the plot. I need to manually modify the rotation parameter, which seems to be cumbersome if the deformation is changed. I need to plot many similar figures.

I define a coordinate named `endpoint` in the end of the first addplot. If I use the coordinate name as the variable in `rotate around`(see commented line), the code doesn't work.

How can I modify the code so that I can only change the file name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nice question! Your approach works in principle, but the problem is that `pgfplots` launches a survey phase during which the `endpoint` coordinate is not known. Therefore I suggest to just read the last coordinate from the table (before you start the `axis`) and use it. This is as automatic as your approach.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{data.dat}
        0.  0.
        0.1 0.00944826
        0.2 0.0308185
        0.3 0.0541806
        0.4 0.0711639
        0.5 0.0760562
        0.6 0.0666065
        0.7 0.0442508
        0.8 0.0136516
        0.9 -0.0183828
        1.  -0.0443726
    \end{filecontents*}
\pagestyle{empty}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableread{data.dat}\data
\pgfplotstablegetrowsof{\data} 
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\NumRows}{\pgfplotsretval-1} 
\pgfplotstablegetelem{\NumRows}{[index]0}\of{\data}
\edef\myx{\pgfplotsretval}
\pgfplotstablegetelem{\NumRows}{[index]1}\of{\data}
\edef\myy{\pgfplotsretval}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
             hide axis,
            colormap/jet,
            point meta rel=per plot,
            ymax=10
        ]
            \addplot[
                mesh,
                point meta=abs(y),
            ] table {\data};
            \addplot[
                mesh,
                x filter/.code={\pgfmathparse{#1+1}\pgfmathresult},
                y filter/.code={\pgfmathparse{#1+-0.0443726}\pgfmathresult},
                rotate around={45:(\myx,\myy)},% works
                ] table {\data};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]